# Adding custom indexes in sharded cluster CSRS(Config Server as replicaSet )?

Tags: mongodb

I am monitoring my ~10TB 5x shards  sharding cluster with prometheus/grafana/mongodb_exporter , but I see mongo_exporter is getting number of chunks grouped by shard from the CSRS server and it is taking more then 2min:

```
 2022-01-18T16:31:48.499+0100 I COMMAND  [conn369096] command config.chunks appName: "mongodb_exporter" command: aggregate { aggregate: "chunks", pipeline: [ { $group: { _id: "$shard", count: { $sum: 1 } } } ], fromMongos: true, cursor: { batchSize: 101 }, lsid: { id: UUID("4b65f5f9-1776-471e-a086-3bee46841edf"), uid: BinData(0, 745F9C5E38C046A7EAF9555E7B0195569974DC916F6DF649D96D26158C1DF113) }, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $replData: 1, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1642519905, 7), signature: { hash: BinData(0, CA16F59A62FEE55E3A1B73F5A45E450B4EFE5F88), keyId: 7004436913486561282 } }, $client: { driver: { name: "mongo-go-driver", version: "v1.5.3" }, os: { type: "linux", architecture: "amd64" }, platform: "go1.16.5", application: { name: "mongodb_exporter" }, mongos: { host: "mymongos:27019", client: "1.2.3.4:54054", version: "4.0.23" } }, $configServerState: { opTime: { ts: Timestamp(1642519905, 7), t: 120 } }, $db: "config" } planSummary: COLLSCAN keysExamined:0 docsExamined:1620394 cursorExhausted:1 numYields:12684 nreturned:5 reslen:707 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 12757 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 12757 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 12757 } } } storage:{} protocol:op_msg 2464ms
```

So the questions:

1. Is it wise to create index in CSRS config.chunks.shard field to speed up this periodical mongodb_exporter aggregation query?
   Tested index creation and I see the aggregation query pick it up only if it is explicitely adviced via HINT:

   ```
   CSRS:PRIMARY> db.chunks.createIndex({shard:1})
   CSRS:PRIMARY> db.chunks.explain("executionStats").aggregate([ { $group: { _id: "$shard", count: { $sum: 1 } } }],{hint:{"shard":1}} )

                                              "inputStage" : {
                                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                                            "shard" : 1
                                                    },

                                 "executionStats" : {
                                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                                    "nReturned" : 1601762,
                                    "executionTimeMillis" : 1377,
                                    "totalKeysExamined" : 1601762,
                                    "totalDocsExamined" : 0



   CSRS:PRIMARY> db.chunks.aggregate([ { $group: { _id: "$shard", count: { $sum: 1 } } }],{hint:{"shard":1}} )
   { "_id" : "s4", "count" : 318174 }
   { "_id" : "s3", "count" : 318086 }
   { "_id" : "s0", "count" : 317933 }
   { "_id" : "s1", "count" : 318020 }
   { "_id" : "s2", "count" : 329549 }
   CSRS:PRIMARY>
   ```

2. Please, advice if is safe adding custom indices in CSRS config  database in general?

Any advice will be highly appreciated ?

Comment: The query has to read the entire collection, thus I guess an index does not make much difference.

Comment: Any optimisation advice , now with 5x shards it takes > 2min , I suppose if we increase data and shards this will become even slower , it do not seems to be an issue at this time but I was wondering if is worth to improve , and not sure if this affects some how balancing , write load or overall performance ...

Comment: You might raise that question with the folks that wrote mongodb_exporter to make sure that query is something it should be doing.

Comment: When I run your query on my Cluster then I get `fromMongos: false` - yours is `fromMongos: true`. No idea why it is different.

Comment: "fromMongos: true" must mean that the query is comming from the mongos which is my case , I got the message from the CSRS logs , but the request was sent from mongo_exporter to mongoses ... , you probably executed directly from CSRS ?

Comment: Surprisingly I get `fromMongos: false` despite I run it from mongos. Maybe not so important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query covers all collections, however usually it should be per collection, i.e. per namespace. In earlier MongoDB release the documents where like this:

```
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("61a7bd45b9a53380435dede7"), 
    "ns": "database.collection", 
    "min": ..., 
    "max": ...., 
    "shard": "shard_02", 
    ...
}
```

Now in MongoDB 5.0 field `ns` is replaced by `uuid` and it looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id": ObjectId("61a7bd45b9a53380435dede7"), 
    "uuid": UUID("322758c1-c52f-4ab6-9eb2-c48fc1634ef7"), 
    "min": ..., 
    "max": ...., 
    "shard": "shard_02", 
    ...
}
```

You should have an unique index on `{uuid: 1, shard: 1, min: 1}`. You can lookup namespace from `config.collections` collection.

Perhaps prometheus/grafana does not take this modification into account.

The `$group` stage can sometimes use an index to find the first document in each group if all of the following criteria are met:

- The `$group` stage is preceded by a `$sort` stage that sorts the field to group by,
- There is an index on the grouped field which matches the sort order and
- The only accumulator used in the `$group` stage is `$first`.

So, I don't think an index on `{shard: 1}` will help